# What is nature of pole at center of magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

We know that a bar magnet has two poles 'North' and 'South' but what is there at the center where two poles meet? please explain me in simple language I am just a physics enthusiast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic poles are not associated with locations contrary to electric poles. Whereas static electric fields emerge from charges, this is not the case for magnetic fields and magnetic monopoles or charges do not exist. A magnetic pole is just a location where field lines can be thought to emerge from the surface of a magnet, or more precisely, where the magnetic field B is perpendicular to the surface of the magnet. The North pole is where B points upward and the South pole is where B points downward. Inside the magnet B is continuous ads it passes through the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a bar magnet, cut off most of the North end and cut off most of the South end, we will still have a bar magnet with a North and a South pole. In fact, we can continue this right down to the centre of the magnet: zooming in right at the centre, it still looks like there is a bar magnet with a North and a South pole.

The same property is true for any piece of a bar magnet. If you chop up a bar magnet into any number of pieces, each of those pieces will have its own North and South pole. This essentially works because each atom in the bar magnet acts like its own little bar magnet; in a bar magnet, all of the little atoms' bar magnets are aligned in the same direction.

It is, in theory, possible that there exist things that would behave differently if you cut them in half. This falls within the realm of the search for magnetic monopoles, which actually might have particles with "North magnetism" and particles with "South magnetism." Nobody has actually found any magnetic monopoles yet, but people are searching!